# Linking static lib into shared lib,are there a better way to make pre declaration?

Tags: c

Example of codes to to illustrate the problem:
file liba.c:

```
 int ajob (void)
 {
     return 19;
 }
```

compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -c liba.c
ar rcs liba.a liba.o
```

file so.h:

```
int ajob (void); 
int sojob (void);
```

file libso.c

```
#include "so.h"
int sojob (void)
{
   return 4;   
}
#if defined(WILLWORK)
void afoo(void)
{
    ajob();
}
#endif
```

compiled with:

```
gcc -shared  -L ./ -o libso.so -la -fPIC libso.c
```

this will not include the ajob function in the shared lib. But this will:

```
gcc -shared  -L ./ -o libso.so -la -fPIC libso.c -DWILLWORK
```

file to test this (appl.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "so.h"
int main(void)
{
    printf ("so + a = %d \n", sojob() + ajob());
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -lso appl.c -L ./  -R ./
```

My question is, is there a more preferred way to include a static lib in a shared lib, avoiding such a dummy function as  "afoo"  ?

Comment: Yes, use  --whole-archive linker flag (-Wl,---whole-archive -la if linked by gcc).

Comment: Works fine now, used : gcc libso.o -shared -L./ '-Wl,--whole-archive' -la '-Wl,--no-whole-archive' -o libso.so